# date and time hide using UIBubbleTableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Ian using UIBubbleTableView for chat application.its working perfectly but i doesn't want to date and time. Any help?

Below is my code:

```
 NSBubbleData *heyBubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithText:@"Hi, this is abcd, how are you?" date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-300] type:BubbleTypeSomeoneElse];
```

tried to send nil to date input but data is not displayed

Any help?how to proceed further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
NSBubbleData *sayBubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithText:textField.text date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] type:BubbleTypeSomeoneElse];
```

If it is not, my idea is you can change in the lib, just check when you pass `date` as `nil`, so the table hide the date to show on.

Comment: working perfectly..thank you..i need spacing between bubbles any idea?

Comment: yeah, in the file UIBubbleTableView.m, in `- (float)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, you could modify this `return MAX(data.insets.top + data.view.frame.size.height + data.insets.bottom+valueYouWantToAdd, self.showAvatars ? 52 : 0);` Hope this help.